# MongoDB aggregation slower with indexes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm facing a rather unexpected behavior with an aggregation. I'm running some performance tests with a collection of ~10M documents which have the form

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    location: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [
            26.38914519633397,
            -42.404163283097745
        ]
    },
    isAvailable: true,
    ...more properties
}
```

with the aggregation :

```js
this.mongo.db.collection('users').aggregate([
    {$limit: 1000000},
    {$match: {
        isAvailable: true,
        location: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere :[
                    position,  //an array like [ 26.3, -42.4]
                    radius  //a number between 0 and 1
        ]}},
    }}
],{allowDiskUse: true}).toArray()
```

The thing is that (everything else being equal) this aggregation takes ~1,8s with indexes (on isAvailable and location) and ~1,65s without these indexes. (Average on 50 aggregationz)

What am i missing ? What am I doing wrong ?

The indexes

```js
{"isAvailable":1}
  //and 
{"location":"2dsphere"}
```

---

Edit: Some cases (10 aggregations average)
(real use case has just another match stage)

**1) Match only**

1. With indexes *~11,5s found 298,845 documents*
2. Without indexes *~9,7s found 298,845 documents*
3. Real use case with indexes *~33,5s found 15,553 documents*
4. Real use case without indexes *~9,3s found 15,553 documents* (wtf)

**2) Limit 1M and then match**

1. With indexes *~1,45s found 29,726 documents*
2. Without indexes *~1,4s found 29,726 documents*
3. Real use case with indexes *~1,8s found 1,525 documents*
4. Real use case without indexes *~1,7s found 1,525 documents*

**3) Match and then limit 100k** (and then another match for 3 and 4)

1. With indexes *~3,6s found 100,000 documents*
2. Without indexes *~3,1s found 100,000 documents*
3. Real use case with indexes *~3,6s found 5,137 documents*
4. Real use case without indexes *~3,1s found 5,137 documents*

---

Edit: Some cases with .explain("executionStats") (Match only, no limit)

**1) With indexes** *~11,4s*

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'database.userProps',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { '$and': [Array] },
    optimizedPipeline: true,
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: { stage: 'FETCH', filter: [Object], inputStage: [Object] },
    rejectedPlans: [ [Object] ]
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 298845,
    executionTimeMillis: 11744,
    totalKeysExamined: 8003852,
    totalDocsExamined: 8003852,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: [Object],
      nReturned: 298845,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1166,
      works: 8003853,
      advanced: 298845,
      needTime: 7705007,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 8021,
      restoreState: 8021,
      isEOF: 1,
      docsExamined: 8003852,
      alreadyHasObj: 0,
      inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          nReturned: 8003852,
          executionTimeMillisEstimate: 184,
          works: 8003853,
          advanced: 8003852,
          needTime: 0,
          needYield: 0,
          saveState: 8039,
          restoreState: 8039,
          isEOF: 1,
          keyPattern: { isAvailable: 1 },
          indexName: 'isAvailable_1',
          isMultiKey: false,
          multiKeyPaths: { isAvailable: [] },
          isUnique: false,
          isSparse: false,
          isPartial: false,
          indexVersion: 2,
          direction: 'forward',
          indexBounds: { isAvailable: [ '[true, true]' ] },
          keysExamined: 8003852,
          seeks: 1,
          dupsTested: 0,
          dupsDropped: 0
      }
    }
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'users',
    pipeline: [ [Object] ],
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'database'
  },
  serverInfo: {...},
  serverParameters: {...},
  ok: 1
}
```

**2) Without indexes** *~9,8s*

```
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'database.userProps',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { '$and': [Array] },
    optimizedPipeline: true,
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: { stage: 'COLLSCAN', filter: [Object], direction: 'forward' },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 298845,
    executionTimeMillis: 9446,
    totalKeysExamined: 0,
    totalDocsExamined: 10000001,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'COLLSCAN',
      filter: [Object],
      nReturned: 298845,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 632,
      works: 10000003,
      advanced: 298845,
      needTime: 9701157,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 10000,
      restoreState: 10000,
      isEOF: 1,
      direction: 'forward',
      docsExamined: 10000001
    }
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'users',
    pipeline: [ [Object] ],
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'database'
  },
  serverInfo: {...},
  serverParameters: {...},
  ok: 1
}
```

**3) With compound index** *~33s*

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'database.userProps',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { '$and': [Array] },
    optimizedPipeline: true,
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: { stage: 'FETCH', filter: [Object], inputStage: [Object] },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 298845,
    executionTimeMillis: 35564,
    totalKeysExamined: 423980,
    totalDocsExamined: 423951,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: [Object],
      nReturned: 298845,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 35281,
      works: 423980,
      advanced: 298845,
      needTime: 125134,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 2239,
      restoreState: 2239,
      isEOF: 1,
      docsExamined: 423951,
      alreadyHasObj: 0,
      inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          nReturned: 423951,
          executionTimeMillisEstimate: 468,
          works: 423980,
          advanced: 423951,
          needTime: 28,
          needYield: 0,
          saveState: 2634,
          restoreState: 2634,
          isEOF: 1,
          keyPattern: [Object],
          indexName: 'isAvailable_1_location_2dsphere',
          isMultiKey: false,
          multiKeyPaths: [Object],
          isUnique: false,
          isSparse: false,
          isPartial: false,
          indexVersion: 2,
          direction: 'forward',
          indexBounds: [Object],
          keysExamined: 423980,
          seeks: 29,
          dupsTested: 0,
          dupsDropped: 0
        }
    }
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'users',
    pipeline: [ [Object] ],
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'database'
  },
  serverInfo: {...},
  serverParameters: {...},
  ok: 1
}
```

Comment: To use indexes with the aggregation pipeline, stages that can make use of indexes like `$match` need to be the first on the pipeline, See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#improve-performance-with-indexes-and-document-filters

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo Thanks but it does not explain why it's slower with indexes and the problem is that without the limit stage it takes ~10s. Any ideas ?

Comment: when you say without the limit stage do you mean you're comparing these two queries `[{$limit: 10000, $match: {}}]` and one where you have `[{$match: {}}]` without a limit

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo Exactly

Comment: Your queries are probably returning different amount of documents. You're limiting the size of one to like `1000` and the one without limit potentially returns more which will take longer. I suggest you actually just switch the order between `$match` and `$limit` and compare the time to make a proper comparison

Comment: What `.explain` says for both queries? Is it a compound index, or 2 separate indexes?

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo Answer edited with some cases, we can clearly see that it is at least equal and sometimes slower with indexes.

Comment: @AlexBlex You want explain in which case ? (They are two separate indexes)

Comment: One with indexes, one without indexes. Both pipelines without $limit - it won't let use indexes even if they are defined.  Mongo usually picks only 1 index, so it's essential to see the explain to understand which one is being used. Please use "ExecutionStats" parameter for `explain`

Comment: @AlexBlex Answer edited with the cases you asked

Comment: `inputStage: [Object]` ?  =) The object is the most interesting part.  From what is visible:     `totalKeysExamined: 423980,  totalDocsExamined: 423951,` the index is not extremely selective - it still had to examine half-million documents. Collscan did a million - just twice as much without any overhead of managing indexes.

Comment: @AlexBlex Answer edited, please note that here the index chosen is 'isAvailable' but the execution time is the same if it's 'location'. (I can choose which one by changing the order in the $match of the aggregation)

Comment: Ok, for the availability index, totalDocsExamined is 8 of 10 mln, basically useless. COLLSCAN is 2 seconds faster because it is optimized for block read of whole collection. Using isAvailable index Mongo reads the index first, than FETCHes (random read) almost the same amount of documents.  It's more interesting with compound index, as it's 3 times slower, but it still says inputStage: [Object].

Comment: @AlexBlex Ah ok, I edited the question, I understand better what happens now. The thing is that it's dummy data, i've no idea of the proportion of isAvailable. So i've no idea if this index is usefull. The thing is even with location index (which should be more restrictive) it takes the same time to execute. Anyway thanks for your time but as I really only want one user i'me going to make some kind of incremental search like search for 100k, search for next 200k etc until a defined value which sould be a lot more fast in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This overall question is very interesting. Even with the available information, there is still a bunch of nuance that is tricky to wade through. Indeed I very much agree with [@Alex Blex in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73203640/mongodb-aggregation-slower-with-indexes#comment129291068_73203640):

> `inputStage: [Object]` ? =) The object is the most interesting part.

The problem with the `[Object]` redaction is likely related to how the MongoDB Shell is configured. Perhaps gather the verbose `explain` outputs again after either upgrading the shell or after increasing the `inspectDepth` setting ([see here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/configure-shell-settings/)).

It would also be helpful to know what version of the database you are using. This is included in the `serverInfo` field of explain output which appears to have been manually redacted up to this point.

The reason the truncated information is so important is because it contains the critical details about how the database is actually using the indexes etc. For example:

```
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: [Object],
      ...
      inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          indexName: 'isAvailable_1_location_2dsphere',       
          indexBounds: [Object],
          ...
```

Here we can see that the database is doing some `filter`ing after `FETCH`ing the data, but we don't know what that filtering is or why it wasn't able to do so during the `IXSCAN` phase (e.g. directly via the `indexBounds` or secondarily as a `filter` during that stage).

Indexes are best at supporting the efficient retrieval of a selective result set. The larger that result set is relative to the total collection size, the less beneficial an index will be in supporting the operation (as was also mentioned by @Alex Blex in the comments). It may very well be the case that the database is not using the index as efficiently as expected, but it could also be the case that environmental factors (including the relative size of the results) are the primary challenges here. There are situations where indexes are not helpful, and indeed part of the optimizer's job is to figure out when it may not be appropriate to use them.

We would only be able to speculate about these components without updated `explain` output to investigate further.

#### Usage of Limit

This was also touched on in the comments, but what is your intention with using `limit` here?

Placing it as the first stage of the aggregation pipeline changes the semantics of what you are asking for. When it is placed first, you are instructing the database to first retrieve that number of documents from the collection and *then* perform subsequent processing on them (such as filtering in a later `$match`). This may be quite different than what your intended semantics (and therefore database behavior) are. The result is that your tests and conclusions from them may not be representative of the actual problem that you are investigating.

As a general pointer, it is always a good idea to `explain` and test the *exact* operation that you intend to run with the application. In this case that likely means removing a preceding `$limit` and having the compound index present. Doing so will greatly improve the applicability of the investigation and the associated suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I did give executionStats.executionStages.inputStage am I wrong ?

Comment: Every `[Object]` value in your explain output represents _more information_ that was returned by the database but the shell itself hid it from us.

Comment: As an example, you can see one of the explains shows the full index bounds (`indexBounds: { isAvailable: [ '[true, true]' ] },`) while a different one, which was presumably had additional layers of nesting, did not (`indexBounds: [Object],`)